# Do I need a UK transit visa for a connecting flight from Saudi Arabia to Canada for my stopover at London Heathrow?

Tags: visas, uk, transit

I am from Syrian and have permanent residence in Saudi Arabia and Permanent Visa to Canada to join my mom there.  I am travelling to Canada via Etihad air flight. I have a stopover halt at London Heathrow Airport for 4 hours 45 minutes to board the connecting flight to Canada. I have a valid permanent visa to travel to Canada; I am unsure whether I will need a Transit visa for the UK. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you a better and more reliable answer: https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/

The airline should also be able to give you the information you seek, as they are liable if they send you without a visa if you actually need one.

Comment: I think I'll stop posting answers... the environment here is a bit too hostile

Comment: I'm sorry.  I did not intend that comment to seem hostile.

Comment: Frankly, I feel a bit squashed by the dominance of a few users in Travel and Expat. And as the some of these users are also very quick with downvotes against new contributors, I would describe the whole environment as hostile, not your last comment in particular. Sometimes there are also emotions involved when the topic is travel/immigration to the country of their nationality. Other SE communities are more peaceful.